# div не доходит до конца страницы

Tags: css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. divы не доходят до конца страницы, всегда остается полоса, всегда body длиннее на несколько пикселов. Я использую сетку бутстрапа, пробовал отключить ее, ничего не меняется. Я так понимаю проблема не в отступах [image: body][image: div]. Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    background-image: url(/images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    font-family: "RobotoRegular", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.main {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 768px;
}
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь инструментами разработчика и посмотрите, что дает лишний отступ

Comment: Но там нет отступа, и в css нет отступов. Что это за полоса?

Comment: ты используешь что-то типа reset или normalize? Если нет, то у браузера есть свои базовые стили, где может вылезать какой-нибудь padding.

Comment: Может, картинка физически меньше? Используете background-size?

Comment: @curveball Я использую сборку готовую, там есть ресет. Сейчас попробовал без сборки (вдруг из-за нее), просто два файла создал php и css, у body выставил margin padding 0, полоса осталась. Такое ощущение, что с кодом она никак не связана вообще.

Comment: @br3t картинка присвоена body, и она встает как положено. Проблема в том, что у body какой то стабильный отступ от нижнего края, который нигде не обозначен. Если пытаться растянуть полупрозрачный див на скринах, то body растягивается вместе с ним и полоса остается.

Comment: а ссылка есть посмотреть или только локально у тебя?

Comment: В идеале - минимально необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы участок кода.

Comment: @curveball Только локально, на хостинге так же было.

Comment: @br3t код в вопрос добавил наверху

Comment: А может виноват кеш?

Comment: Мне аж интересно, кто первый угадает правильный ответ) А может там Position:relative у футера со сдвигом вверх? Без живого примера тут нечего обсуждать

Comment: @РашенБеар я сверху добавил кусок кода, с ним полоса тоже есть. Там один единственный див - main, который доходит почти до конца страницы, но body всегда длиннее и это нигде не прописано, я даже не знаю где искать уже.